# Range Partition Time Data Postgres

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-partitioning

When it comes to CRUD operations I am curious when it is better to range partition time series data with an index on the column being used as the range versus just having a index on time.

So for a simple example if you have a table with three columns (time, device_id, value):

- In the first case I range partition the table on time along with create an index on time.
- In the second case, I just have one monolithic table with just an index on time.

My questions based on anyone who has done this before is what are the benefits of the range parition option when it comes to performance (primarily speed) versus the monolithic table with an index for each of the CRUD operations and on a highlevel why is that based on how the database operates.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly improve the speed of some queries, particularly if you aggregate or join in a way that matches partitioning. However, most queries will become slower on a partitioned table.

One potential gain would be to *drop* the index on the partitioning key and use a sequential scan on the whole partition instead. That will perhaps be slower, but it can make data modifications faster.

Comment: I could see slower queries due to having to union results from 2 children tables. Could that be offset by the fact that you resolve to children table faster and then can search those tables faster than ln(n) if the monolithic db was indexed as a B-tree? I guess better put when could a query be faster with range partitioning as that is of concern for the application?

Comment: The speed of an index scan is independent from the size of an index. Better get resigned to the fact that partitioning makes most queries slightly slower.

Comment: I could see that for a SELECT * from data;, but would that be different for a SELECT from data where between [d1] and [d2]; and the range is limited to one child table? At some point I will validate that, but trying to avoid setting myself up for a data migration out the gate if someone is willing to share their experiences.

Comment: That range scan will be faster if there is no index on the column, because you won't have to scan all partitions.